# Shipment method only available for specific days

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping-methods

we are using magento 1.8.1ce.

Is there a way to use a shipment method which only is available between specific times on specific days.

We are looking for a method which is only available between thursday 15:00 and friday 16:00.

How can i do this?

i did see an post which uses an attribute for filtering.
But we need it to be applied to all products ...

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of a duplicate. How to filter:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7151/217

You just have to adjust the check and include date and the correct shipping code. If you have any problems with this, please open another question, describe what you have done (maybe link this or the other question) and explain what you expected and what happened instead.

You need to add to the method:

```
if ($carrierCode === 'YOUR_CODE' && $nowBetweenThursdayFiveTeenAndFridaySixTeen){
    return false;
}
```

I'm letting you implement `$nowBetweenThursdayFiveTeenAndFridaySixTeen`

Comment: This post is mainly about using an attribute for a specific item .... For us it has to do with all items

Comment: Updated the post, I hope now is clear what you have to do.

Comment: Thank you. I Will try this. I guess I have to put this in the shipping file of the checkout extension.

Comment: You need to rewrite `shipping/shipping`

Comment: Do you mean this file: checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml?

Comment: did you read the other post? Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping::collectCarrierRates()